# define offset in foreach loop

Tags: php, pagination, offset

I have already a class pagination implemented in one of my website by a programmer.Now I would like to implement it to another. The difference is that he was using limit and offset and take data from a database and now there is a foreach loop and I am a beginner in php.
So there is the code:

```
$page = !empty($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$per_page = 10;
$total_count = 25; \\ should be dynamic here

$pagination = new Pagination($page, $per_page, $total_count);

foreach(...

)
```

the pagination class contains methods which determinate if there is a previous page,next page etc. and those are working fine . Just that I am getting just first 10 in all 3 pages.
Thanks in advance!

Pagination class looks like this

```
<?php

// This is a helper class to make paginating 
// records easy.
class Pagination {

  public $current_page;
  public $per_page;
  public $total_count;

  public function __construct($page=1, $per_page=10, $total_count=0){
    $this->current_page = (int)$page;
    $this->per_page = (int)$per_page;
    $this->total_count = (int)$total_count;
  }

  public function offset() {
    // Assuming 20 items per page:
    // page 1 has an offset of 0    (1-1) * 20
    // page 2 has an offset of 20   (2-1) * 20
    //   in other words, page 2 starts with item 21
    return ($this->current_page - 1) * $this->per_page;
  }

  public function total_pages() {
    return ceil($this->total_count/$this->per_page);
    }

  public function previous_page() {
    return $this->current_page - 1;
  }

  public function next_page() {
    return $this->current_page + 1;
  }

    public function has_previous_page() {
        return $this->previous_page() >= 1 ? true : false;
    }

    public function has_next_page() {
        return $this->next_page() <= $this->total_pages() ? true : false;
    }


}

?>
```

Comment: What you are asking here is not clear. Can you provide further information on what you are trying to achieve, and what you have tried so far? Have you tried contacting your developer for help?

Comment: It would be easier with a `for` loop; but you would need to give some details about `Pagination` class.

Comment: Can you also show your sql query?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM photographs ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT {$per_page} ";
    $sql .= "OFFSET {$pagination->offset()}";

Comment: What you need is `array_slice`